# Border Fade Out(from top to bottom)

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a

`border-left: 3px solid #F90;`

and I want it to fade out. I want it to be opacity 1 on top and 0 at the bottom. I've tried this and it does not work.

```
border-left: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,153,0,1), rgba(255,153,0,1), rgba(255,153,0,0));
```

EDIT: This kind of thing work with `background-image` on a `<hr>` from left to right.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle link... ?

Comment: Hope it works: http://jsfiddle.net/HQe7x/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you will get the desired outcome from trying that approach.  I would create 3px wide `<div>` to the left of your main `<div>` and set the thin `<div>`'s `background` style to the gradient.

Comment: I agree with the above answer. I did something similar when helping someone achieve a "gradient border" Take a look at the code here: http://codepen.io/BJack/pen/gyxGs. Nest your content within another div, and use the outside div to give the appearance of a border. You can apply the same principal but to give the appearance of just a left hand border. **edited the pen to show what you need**

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Did that div thingy and it works. Here's the fiddle if anyone needs it:http://jsfiddle.net/HQe7x/14/